# Как протестировать метод, который меняет буквы в слове?

Tags: java, юнит-тесты

Начал вникать в unit test, потренировался на всяких простых арифметических операциях, все понятно.
Есть конкретный метод который меняет буквы в слове:

```
private static char[] exchangeCharInWord(char[] charArray, int first, int last ){
        char tmp;
        tmp=charArray[first]; 
        charArray[first]=charArray[last]; 
        charArray[last]=tmp;
        return charArray;
    }
```

никак не могу понять что мне здесь проверять.Вот начал писать...

```
public class TestMyClass {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        MyClass c = new MyClass();
        char[] word = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'o'};
        int first = 0;
        int last = word.length-1;

    }
}
```

Comment: Отдаете внутрь `HELO, 0, 3`, сравниваете результат с `OELH`. Что у вас вызывает затруднения?

Comment: Проверять надо работоспособность метода (цепочки методов). Даешь своей функции `exchangeCharInWord` входные параметры (к примеру `"abd",0,1`) и сравниваешь результат с тем, что должно получится (а должно "bad") в твоём случае при помощи `org.junit.Assert.assertArrayEquals`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Необходимо выделить возможные входные данные метода и результаты работы метода с этими данными. Например, такие тесты:

1. Тест метода на корректных данных (проверяем, что метод правильно меняет местами символы массива):

`public void validInput_shouldSwap() {...}`

2. Тест метода при отрицательных значениях индексов (индекса):

`public void negativeIndex_shouldThrow() {...}`

3. Тест метода, если индексы выходят за границы массива:

`public void outOfBoundIndexValues_shouldThrow() {...}`

В зависимости от реализации метода 2 и 3 тесты можно объединить в один.

Соответственно внутри каждого теста проверяете результаты работы метода с ожидаемыми.

Answer (score 4):

Немного обобщу ответ от Pavel Parshin. Для практически любого метода должны быть юнит-тесты нескольких типов:

1. Проверить, что метод корректно работает с корректными входными данными. В вашем случае -- действительно меняет символы в позициях `first` и `last` местами.
2. Проверить "угловые случаи". В вашем случае -- когда значения `first` и `last` совпадают. Строка при этом измениться не должна.
3. Проверить работу метода с некорректными данными. В вашем случае -- когда один из индексов (или оба) выходят за пределы массива. Обычно метод должен падать с исключением типа ArgumentException.

Второй случай может вам "подсказать" добавить проверку: если индексы совпадают, то можно просто выйти из метода.

Третий случай выявляет одно из преимуществ написания тестов -- вы забыли проверить входные данные на валидность. Упавший тест "напомнит" вам об этом.

Причем я бы рекомендовал писать тесты в "обратном" порядке -- от некорректных случаев к корректным. Это позволит сразу указать все нужные проверки и обойти самые простые ошибки.