# Как писать тесты?

Tags: eclipse, юнит-тесты, junit, test-driven-development

Разбираюсь с Junit в Eclipse. 
Eсть LRU и LFU алгоритмы с вложенными классами. 
Вот LRU класс:

```
package Main;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class LRUAlgoritm<K, V> implements Cache<K, V>{
     private LRUStorage storage; 

     public LRUAlgoritm(int capacity) {
         this.storage = new LRUStorage(capacity);
     }

    @Override
    public V get(K key) {

        return storage.get(key);
    }

    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        return storage.put(key,value);
    }

    private class LRUStorage extends LinkedHashMap<K, V>{
        private final int capacity;

        private LRUStorage (int capacity){
            this.capacity = capacity;
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<K, V> eldest){
            return size()>capacity; 
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return  "storage= " + storage ;
    }
}
```

Вот LFU класс:

```
package Main;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;

public class LFUCache<K, V> implements Cache<K, V> {

    private final LinkedHashMap<K, Node> storage; //the declaration of the variable "storage" for storing data with key type "K" and value type "Node".
    private final int capacity;

    public LFUCache(int capacity) {
        if (capacity <= 0) {//validation of the capacity on the negative and the zero value
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Capacity should be more than 0");
        }
        this.capacity = capacity;
        this.storage = new LinkedHashMap<>(capacity, 1); //initialization of variable "storage" - data storage. 
                                                            //Inside the parentheses: the specified initial capacity and load factor = 1 
    }

//overriding methods "get" and "put" to be implemented from the interface "Cache"
    @Override
    public V get(K key) {
        Node node = storage.get(key);//the get method of LinkedHashMap class according to the
                                        //"http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html" 
                                        //returns "null" if the requested key is missing or 
                                        //has the value - a Hash mapping key if the key exists in the cache storage "storage"
        if (node == null) {//check the value of the variable "node" to NULL
            return null;
        }
        return node.incrementFrequency().getValue();//if the value of the variable "node" is not NULL, 
                                                    //then the called method to increase the frequency on the unit and 
                                                    //obtain take associated with the key "key" variable value "value"
    }

    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
       //   if (storage.get(key)!=null&& Objects.equals(value, storage.get(key).getValue()))
        //{return storage.get(key).incrementFrequency().getValue();}//verification of the presence of the led element in the cache storage "storage" 
                                                                //if the element is present then return the value from the cache store

        doEvictionIfNeeded(key);//verification of occupancy of the cache storage, and the presence of the inserted key in the cache storage "storage"

        Node oldNode = storage.put(key, new Node(value));//the put method, inherited from Map interface, returns the previous value associated with key, 
                                                            //or null if there was no mapping for key
        if (oldNode == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return oldNode.getValue();
    }

// method to displace the old value with the least frequency when the storage of the cached data is completely filled
    private void doEvictionIfNeeded(K putKey) {
        if (storage.size() < capacity) {//verification of occupancy of the cache storage
            return;
        }
        long minFrequency = Long.MAX_VALUE;//the maximum assignable value for a variable of type Long
        K keyToRemove = null;
        for (Map.Entry<K, Node> entry : storage.entrySet()) {//search cash store the minimum value of frequency the "frequency" of all those elements
            if (Objects.equals(entry.getKey(), putKey)) {
                //no eviction required cause element already exists, we just need to replace it
                return;
            }
            if (minFrequency >= entry.getValue().getFrequency()) {
                minFrequency = entry.getValue().getFrequency();
                keyToRemove = entry.getKey();
            }
        }
        storage.remove(keyToRemove);//removal item's key with the minimum number of calls
    }

//an inner class "Node" in the object which is stored the value "value". 
    //And is created for this value a variable to hold the frequency "frequency" to the value "value'
    private class Node { 
        private final V value;
        private long frequency;

        //create a constructor with a parameter (a value of type V) to write the value in the node object.
        //And setting the initial value of the frequency of reference to "value" - "frequency" = 1
        public Node(V value) {
            this.value = value;
            this.frequency = 1;
        }

        public V getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public long getFrequency() {
            return frequency;
        }

        public Node incrementFrequency() {// method to increase frequency by one(+1)
            ++frequency;
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Node [value=" + value + ", frequency=" + frequency + "]";
        }

    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "storage = "+ storage + ", capacity=" + capacity ;
    }
}
```

Для LRU алгоритма я сделал тест класс для класса LRUStorage IDE сгенерировала код класса с одним единственным методом:

```
package Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestLRUAlgoritm {
    @Test
    public final void testRemoveEldestEntryEntryOfKV() {
        fail("Not yet implemented");
    }
}
```

Каким образом его теперь протестировать? 
метод removeEldestEntry() это переопределенный метод LinkedHashMap ? какие значения ему отдавать, что бы они адекватны для тестирования?  Пересмотрел и Ткача, Немчинского и Владыкина на простых примерах какие данные передать и какой ассерт взять понятно(добавляем 2 и 2 и ждем 4), здесь же голову сломал, кучу статей перечитал ничего не понимаю, помогите разобраться?

Comment: поясните, что именно вы хотите тестировать (какую функциональность) и зачем?

Comment: @  Mikhail Vaysman я только пытаюсь разобраться, что нужно теститровать и какую именно функциональность необходимо тестировать.  В моем примере (class LRUAlgoritm) есть три метода во внешнем классе LRUAlgoritm (get, put, toString) и один во внутреннем классе LRUStorage (removeEldestEntry). Все они переопределенные. Нужно ли тестировать их логику? Ведь по правилам нужно покрывать тестами 100% кода? Если да, то какие параметры и что на выходе тогда должно быть?

Comment: по каким правилам? Зачем вы хотите тестироваться?

Comment: @ Mikhail Vaysman задание звучит так: покрыть unit-тестами кеш алгоритмы на 100%

Comment: как производится подсчет покрытия?

Comment: я его проверяю JaCoCo. Решение преподу уже отправил покрытие классов сделал на 100%, являются ли тесты "честными"  это другой вопрос, но что -то наделал))

Comment: @ Mikhail Vaysman Само правило, как я понял, звучит так, что все ветки логики кода должны быть проверены максимально изолированно друг от друга. В идеале вначале нужно писать тест. затем код.

Comment: если речь о TDD, то да тесты до кода. по поводу веток не понял. но вы прочитайте про уровни покрытия - C0, C1, C2, C3, C4. обычно дальше C1 идти не стоит.

Answer (score 3):

Юнит-тесты призваны тестировать публичный контракт классов, а не имплементацию. Отсюда несколько выводов:

1. Не нужно тестировать приватные методы или классы. Об `LRUStorage` можно забыть.
2. Нужно тестировать публичные методы и классы. Это `LRUAlgoritm` и `LFUCache`.

Давайте попробуем написать тесты для `LRUAlgoritm`. Этот класс представляет из себя LRU кэш, а значит, обладает следующим контрактом:

- если мы положили в него значение, оно должно быть доступно
- если мы не положили в него значение, оно не должно быть доступно
- если мы удалили из него значение, оно больше недоступно
- если размер кэша превысил заданный порог, самое "старое" значение должно быть удалено

Этот упрощенный список (вы можете дополнить его) сразу дает нам список тест-кейсов, глядя на который мы можем начать писать тесты. Дополнительные примеры определения контракта для написания юнит-тестов можно найти [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562065/106), [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/485076/106) и [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/507075/106).

Первый тест-кейс (на Java давно уже не пишу, вполне вероятны ошибки):

```
public void testPut_ValueShouldBeAvailableByKey() {
    LFUCache<int, String> cache = new LFUCache<int, String>(1);
    cache.put(1, "value");

    String value = cache.get(1);
    Assert.areEqual("value", value, "Unexpected value");
}
```

Второй кейс:

```
public void testGet_ValueShouldNotBeAvailableByKeyIfWasNotStored() {
    LFUCache<int, String> cache = new LFUCache<int, String>(1);

    String value = cache.get(1);
    // в зависимости от поведения get может выбрасывать исключение, 
    // соответственно тест тоже должен измениться
    Assert.areEqual(null, value, "Expected to get no value");
}
```

Третий кейс:

```
public void testRemove_ValueShouldNotBeAvailableByKey() {
    LFUCache<int, String> cache = new LFUCache<int, String>(1);
    cache.put(1, "value");
    cache.remove(1);

    String value = cache.get(1);
    Assert.areEqual(null, value);
}
```

Четвертый кейс:

```
public void testPut_LRUValueShouldNotBeAvailableByKeySizeIsGreaterThanCapacity() {
    LFUCache<int, String> cache = new LFUCache<int, String>(1);
    cache.put(1, "value1");
    cache.put(2, "value2");

    String value = cache.get(1);
    Assert.areEqual(null, value);

    String value = cache.get(2);
    Assert.areEqual("value2", value);
}
```

В качестве упражнения по аналогичной схеме составьте контракт `LFUCache` и напишите для него тесты. Главное думайте о контракте, об обязательствах класса/конкретного метода, а не о реализации, не заглядывайте внутрь методов.